# cakePHP - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have some error about this code. Problem in certificate_controller.ctp

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

function index() {
    $this->Certification->recursive = 0;
    $this->Trainee->recursive = 0;
    //$this->set('certifications', $this->paginate());
    $this->set('viewCertificate',$this->View Certificate->find('list'));
    $this->set('courses',$this->Course->find('list'));
    $this->set('locations',$this->Location->find('list'));
    $this->set('trainees',$this->Trainee->find('list'));
    //$this->Trainee->recursive = 0;

$locations = $this->Location->find('list', array('order'=>'name ASC'));
//$this->set(compact('courses','locations','trainees'));
}
```

Thank for advance

Comment: Please provide the line number, the error should contain it.

Answer (score 5):

I would say something wrong with this line:

```
$this->set('viewCertificate',$this->View Certificate->find('list'));
```

Not sure what the model name is but surely no spaces.